# Mezzio => Service not registered

Tags: zend-framework, middleware, mezzio

I have created a new module named ModuleA, which contains a middleware named MiddlewareA. I also have created a route (e.g. "login") which has MiddlewareA in its pipeline.

When I send a request to the path "login", get response which states that

```
Service MiddlewareA not registered
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have added the new module to the composer.json file of the project, like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/App/src/",
        "ModuleA\\": "src/ModuleA/src/"
    }
},
```

After that please run this command on the project route:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Please proceed these steps every time you create a new Module.